# reached end of file while parsing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8

ok so i finished my program that used to be here and it works fine but it said there is an error on the last line of code where it identifies my title jTextField

```
package trigonomityhelper;

/*This program was mae by andrew cameron
 *on september 25th 2016
 *to help people with trigonometric functions
 */
public class TrigonomityHelperUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TrigonomityHelperUI
 */
public TrigonomityHelperUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    title = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    sin = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cos = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tan = new javax.swing.JButton();
    csc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    sec = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cot = new javax.swing.JButton();
    asin = new javax.swing.JButton();
    acos = new javax.swing.JButton();
    atan = new javax.swing.JButton();
    acsc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    asec = new javax.swing.JButton();
    acot = new javax.swing.JButton();
    calculate = new javax.swing.JButton();
    in = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    out = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    background = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 330));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 330));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 330));
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    title.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    title.setText("<html>Trigonometry <br>           Helper</html>");
    getContentPane().add(title);
    title.setBounds(120, 10, 100, 50);

    sin.setText("sin");
    sin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sinActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(sin);
    sin.setBounds(240, 23, 70, 20);

    cos.setText("cos");
    cos.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cosActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(cos);
    cos.setBounds(240, 43, 70, 20);

    tan.setText("tan");
    tan.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tanActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(tan);
    tan.setBounds(240, 63, 70, 20);

    csc.setText("csc");
    csc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cscActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(csc);
    csc.setBounds(240, 83, 70, 20);

    sec.setText("sec");
    sec.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            secActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(sec);
    sec.setBounds(240, 103, 70, 20);

    cot.setText("cot");
    cot.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cotActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(cot);
    cot.setBounds(240, 123, 70, 20);

    asin.setText("asin");
    asin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            asinActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(asin);
    asin.setBounds(310, 23, 70, 20);

    acos.setText("acos");
    acos.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            acosActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(acos);
    acos.setBounds(310, 43, 70, 20);

    atan.setText("atan");
    atan.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            atanActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(atan);
    atan.setBounds(310, 63, 70, 20);

    acsc.setText("acsc");
    acsc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            acscActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(acsc);
    acsc.setBounds(310, 83, 70, 20);

    asec.setText("asec");
    asec.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            asecActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(asec);
    asec.setBounds(310, 103, 70, 20);

    acot.setText("acot");
    acot.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            acotActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(acot);
    acot.setBounds(310, 123, 70, 20);

    calculate.setText("calculate");
    calculate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(calculate);
    calculate.setBounds(300, 150, 80, 23);

    in.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(in);
    in.setBounds(40, 240, 300, 30);

    out.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(out);
    out.setBounds(10, 270, 360, 20);

    background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/trigonomityhelper/TrigAngles.gif"))); // NOI18N
    background.setToolTipText("Type the number which you need to calculate, select the calculation type, and then click calculate to get your answer.");
    getContentPane().add(background);
    background.setBounds(0, -40, 400, 340);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

// define global variables
String sInput;
int type = 0;
double input, output;

// make custom selection/recoloration button method
private void select (int a, int b, int c) {
    //recolor selected button
    switch (a) {
        case 1: sin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 2: cos.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 3: tan.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 4: csc.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 5: sec.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 6: cot.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 7: asin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 8: acos.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 9: atan.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 10:acsc.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 11:asec.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        case 12:acot.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
                break;
        default:break;
    }
    //set type equal to b
    type = b;
    //recolor last button black
    switch (c) {
        case 1: sin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 2: cos.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 3: tan.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 4: csc.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 5: sec.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 6: cot.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 7: asin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 8: acos.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 9: atan.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 10:acsc.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 11:asec.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        case 12:acot.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
                break;
        default:break;
    }
}

private void sinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select sine
    select(1, 1, type);
}                                   

private void cosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select cosine
    select(2, 2, type);
}                                   

private void tanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select tangent
    select(3, 3, type);
}                                   

private void cscActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select cosecant
    select(4, 4, type);
}                                   

private void secActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select secant
    select(5, 5, type);
}                                   

private void cotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select cotangent
    select(6, 6, type);
}                                   

private void asinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arcsine
    select(7, 7, type);
}                                    

private void acosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arccosine
    select(8, 8, type);
}                                    

private void atanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arctangent
    select(9, 9, type);
}                                    

private void acscActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arcsecant
    select(10, 10, type);
}                                    

private void asecActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arccosecant
    select(11, 11, type);
}                                    

private void acotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    //set color to blue and all other colors to balck, select arccotangent
    select(12, 12, type);
}                                    

private void calculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //use selected method to run the apropriate calculation and output an answer
    if (type == 0) {
        out.setText("No conversion method was selected");
    } else {
        sInput = in.getText();
        in.setText("");
        try {
            input = Double.parseDouble(sInput);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            out.setText("The input was not a number");
            return;
        }

        switch (type) {
            case 1: output = Math.sin(input);
                    out.setText("The sine of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 2: output = Math.cos(input);
                    out.setText("The cosine of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 3: output = Math.tan(input);
                    out.setText("The tangent of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 4: output = (1/Math.sin(input));
                    out.setText("The secant of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 5: output = (1/Math.cos(input));
                    out.setText("The cosecant of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 6: output = (1/Math.tan(input));
                    out.setText("The cotangent of "+input+" is "+output);
                    break;
            case 7: output = Math.asin(input);
                    out.setText("The arcsine of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            case 8: output = Math.acos(input);
                    out.setText("The arccosine of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            case 9: output = Math.atan(input);
                    out.setText("The arctangent of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            case 10:output = Math.pow((1/Math.asin(input)),-1);
                    out.setText("The arcsecant of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            case 11:output = Math.pow((1/Math.acos(input)),-1);
                    out.setText("The arccosecant of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            case 12:output = Math.pow((1/Math.atan(input)),-1);
                    out.setText("The arccotangent of "+input+" is "+output+" Radians");
                    break;
            default:out.setText("No calculation type has been chosen");
                    break;
        }
    }
}                                         


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TrigonomityHelperUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TrigonomityHelperUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TrigonomityHelperUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TrigonomityHelperUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new TrigonomityHelperUI().setVisible(true);
    });
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton acos;
private javax.swing.JButton acot;
private javax.swing.JButton acsc;
private javax.swing.JButton asec;
private javax.swing.JButton asin;
private javax.swing.JButton atan;
private javax.swing.JLabel background;
private javax.swing.JButton calculate;
private javax.swing.JButton cos;
private javax.swing.JButton cot;
private javax.swing.JButton csc;
private javax.swing.JTextField in;
private javax.swing.JLabel out;
private javax.swing.JButton sec;
private javax.swing.JButton sin;
private javax.swing.JButton tan;
private javax.swing.JLabel title;//this is the faulty line of code
// End of variables declaration
```

so my question now, is how do i make this last line of code not be "erroneous", because the program works fine.

Comment: Your question is very scant on detail and code, and to help you, please first help us by improving your question. Tell the details, show the pertinent code, preferably a [mcve], and most important, write your question with your audience in mind -- think "what will they need to know to fully understand my problem and code and be able to help me".

Comment: Also, have you added ActionListeners to your buttons? That's where you would usually perform actions on button press.

Comment: `"...so what im looking for is a line of code that will affect all jbuttons, and a way to reference my jbuttons using that private void method.(does not need to be private void that's just the way i make code lines like that)"` -- makes no sense to me. Please improve further.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am using netbeans so it has autogenerated action listeners, ill edit to include my whole code

Comment: In the future (and now) don't use links to code. Only show code here as code-formatted text. Otherwise your question will be of no use to future visitors to this site. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: In addition to the recommendations given so far, I'd like to give a "meta-recommendation": If you want to get started with Swing, I'd *strongly* recommend to not use GUI builders. You'll sooner or later force yourself (and others, here) to dig through a wall of ugly, auto-generated code (that you don't understand at all). There would be much cleaner, more elegant, and possibly even simpler ways of creating this trigonometry helper application, once you have some basic knowledge about layout managers, buttons and action listeners. Just a hint.

Comment: ya im just using it because its for my gr 12 cource, and for the most part i am able to understand whats going on with the code

Comment: Somehow I do not see the last `}` of the class. It was deleted

Answer (score 2):

You are not required to use NetBean's "auto-generated" ActionListeners. Instead create your **own** ActionListener, add it to all JButtons that you wish to check, and in the listener, get the pushed button via the listener's ActionEvent parameter, specifically the `getSource()` method.

For example:

```
ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();  // here's the button that was pressed
        source.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    }   
}
```

Of course and again, for this listener to work, you'd need to add it to JButtons.

Comment: yes that would work but i also need it to recolor all jButtons to black when it is clicked to visually undo the selection

Comment: @AndrewCameron: If you mean all the other buttons, then create an `ArrayList<JButton>` put all your buttons in the list, in the above action listener use a for loop to turn all buttons black **before** changing the pressed one to blue.

Comment: @AndrewCameron: otherwise, use a JToggleButton and ButtonGroup.

Comment: ok thanks that will work, but is complicated, ill finish my code an let you know when it is updated so you see what i mean clearly

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels I've updated my code, and finished my program, i would be happy even if you told me whats wrong with the way i referenced jButtons in my method.